# Pending Checkins Visual Studio 2005 ASP solution

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic, visual-studio-2005, legacy

I have a legacy ASP website in TFS which on every time I open the solution it `Updates Pending Checkins` for about 5000 files.

I am also getting a warning upon opening saying the `mssccprj.scc file is missing`

Is this the expected behavior and does the missing `mssccprj.scc file` have any effect on this lengthy update (takes about 10 minutes to complete) which happens every time opening the solution?